# Vue - Passing arrays as arguments

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to pass two arrays as arguments to a function that's triggered on button click,  but I get this error:
'Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined. What's is going wrong?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app2">
    <button @click="filterParesImpares(impares, numeros, getImpares)">Impares</button>

    <ul>
      <li v-for="impar in impares">{{impar}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <script>
    const vueCles = {
      data() {
        return {
          numeros: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
          impares: [],
          pares: []
        }
      },

      methods: {
        filterParesImpares: function (a2, a1, f) {
          return this.a2 = this.a1.filter(f)
        },

        getImpares: n => n % 2 !== 0
      }
    }


    const app2 = Vue.createApp(vueCles).mount("#app2")
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a misunderstanding what the function parameters do:

```js
filterParesImpares: function (a2, a1, f) {
  return this.a2 = this.a1.filter(f)
},
```

1. `this.a2 = ...` does not write to `this.numeros`, it literally tries to write `this.a2`.
2. Similarly, `this.a1.filter` does not exist.

Either you supply the name of the data properties or their values.

**Fix the `.filter` call**

To fix your immediate problem, write `a1.filter`, so remove the `this.`, because `this.a1` does not exist.

**Fix the function's parameters**

If you change your function to supply names (change the call to `filterParesImpares('impares', 'numeros', getImpares)`), you can use them like this:

```js
filterParesImpares: function (a2, a1, f) {
  this[a2] = this[a1].filter(f);
  return this[a2];
},
```

**Javascript object access:**

The reason this works is because JavaScript allows access to object properties the normal way (`object.something`), as well as if the object was an array with strings as indexes (`object['something']`).
This makes it possible to put the name of an object property in a variable and access the respective object property.

And yes, this has nothing to do with Vue, this is a language feature of JavaScript.

See [MDN about Object and properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#objects_and_properties)

Comment: Hi Peter. Changin the function's parameters worked, but I'm not understanding exactly the reason why. Could you elaborate a little, please about the use of that single quotes and array access notation in this particular scenario? Regards.

Comment: Okay I'll give a more in-depth answer. The reason this works is because accessing object properties like this is a language feature of JavaScript (see [Object properties at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#objects_and_properties))

Answer (score 1):

No need to pass the data properties as parameters in the event handler, just get access to them inside the method using `this` :

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app2">
    <button @click="filterParesImpares">Impares</button>

    <ul>
      <li v-for="impar in impares">{{impar}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <script>
    const vueCles = {
      data() {
        return {
          numeros: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
          impares: [],
          pares: []
        }
      },

      methods: {
        filterParesImpares: function () {
          return this.impares = this.numeros.filter(this.getImpares)
        },

        getImpares: n => n % 2 !== 0
      }
    }


    const app2 = Vue.createApp(vueCles).mount("#app2")
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi @Boussadjra Brahim. I know that way works.  But I would like to understand how to make it work passing the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the function `filterParesImpares` is trying to access component's `a1` and `a2` with `this` - doesn't exists.
In your component the only values you can get with `this` are: `numeros`, `impares` and `pares`.
To fix you problem, just remove the `this` from the function:

```js
filterParesImpares: function (a2, a1, f) {
  // return this.a2 = this.a1.filter(f)
  return a2 = a1.filter(f)
}
```

Comment: that doesn't work. It doesn't throws any error in the console, but the button doesn't do what it has to do, that is show the array result in the list, and if you log it from the console it shows empty.